# Rest endpoint for fetching data with 2 input params - should the type of fetch be explicit or determine it implicitly?

Tags: rest, web, api-design

I'm building an endpoint, let's call it `/explore`, where data can be requested in two ways:

1. Provide a `lat,lng` as required params with some optional/default params to find results within a certain distance of a location.  This is useful for clients that are perhaps displaying a list view of results.
2. Provide a bounding box `NE lat,lng`, `SW lat,lng` as required params to find results within that region.  This would be useful for clients that are using a map view.

What is considered a better practice in this case?

Should the API consumer provide an explicit `type=map` or `type=list`, or should I the developer allow the consumer to pass EITHER a bounding box or latLng pair and based on the inputs determine what to send back?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would decide based on whether a single coordinate was passed or a bounding box. That prevents a class of errors where the type equals bounding-box, but only a single coordinate is passed in (or vice versa)

The first request in the list below would return a list, where the second would return the bounding box.

```
GET /explore?coord=lat,lng

GET /explore?ne=lat,lng&sw=lat,lng
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's pretty cool.  How would you handle an error if the user sends a bad request?  For example, if all 3 things (coord, ne, sw) are sent, etc.  What would be a good error message?

Comment: Make sure to return an HTTP 400 Bad Request response. The body could contain a message with something like: 'Please send 'coord' or 'ne'&'sw' parameters.